# Mysql query that can grab data from two tables with specific info

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is with my query. I need to select data from two tables, table1 has a field category, which is category id, table2 has field id which is category id. I need to select data by months, for example if we choose february i'm counting everything in that table in selected period and grouping by category id. And for example in selected month in table1 there is no category id=3, ten take it from table2 and make that category value=0. And if in the March period in table1 is category with id=3 then count all values with that category id.

i have done one select but it is not right.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT count(*) as counter, category, (select category from categories where id=leads.category) as categoryname, clientcode , language                   
                  FROM leads   
                  WHERE synced > %s and synced < %s
                  GROUP BY category, clientcode 
               UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 as counter, id as category, category as categoryname, 0 as clientcode, language  FROM categories WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT category FROM leads)
                  GROUP BY category, clientcode ",$starttime, $endtime );
```

Thank you for your help, hope you understand what i need.

a lot of text...

**I solved this :**

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT count(*) as counter, category, (select category from categories where id=leads.category) as categoryname, clientcode , language                   
                      FROM leads   
                      WHERE synced > %s and synced < %s
                      GROUP BY category, clientcode 
                   UNION ALL
                      SELECT 0 as counter, id as category, category as categoryname, 0 as clientcode, language  FROM categories WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT category FROM leads WHERE synced > %s and synced < %s)
                      GROUP BY category, clientcode ",$starttime, $endtime, $starttime, $endtime );
```

Comment: Could you put a small graphical representation of your DB ?

Comment: I have written it in main article

Comment: @MariusGentvilas: Please add your solution (with a short description what with that code did made it) as an *answer* below. Then accept it later to mark your question as solved (yes it is fine that you answer your own question and also that you accept that then).